# Code First Enums not added to Database

Tags: .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5

I have created .NET4.0 application and using Entity Framework v5.0 with it. Then I read that enums could not be mapped with .NET4.0, it should be .NET 4.5

Then I changed all projects' targeting framework to .NET 4.5 but it doesnt work either, until I  created newly .NET 4.5 projects and copying files from .NET 4.0 version.

So is setting targeting framework doesnt work or should I do an extra step if I came across similar situation again ?

*Note: I am using VS 2012*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update EF package once you change target framework to .NET 4.5 because EF 5.0 for .NET 4.0 is different (it is actually EF 4.4) than EF 5.0 for .NET 4.5.